# R: Change rows based on unique values of other rows

Tags: r

I have a large data set with many repeated values in one column, but the rest of the columns have missing values that I would like to fill in.

```
id <- rep(1:3, 3:1)
name <- c("sam", "sam", "", "mike", "", "tom")
df<- data.frame(id, name)

id name
1  sam
1  sam
1     
2  mike
2     
3  tom
```

Because of the nature of the original data, id and name fields are both factors (~2000 unique ID values, acros 45000 rows).
I would like to fill in the missing values based on

Ive tried `unique()` and `duplicated()`, but having difficulty with the replacement.
I would like to use a base package if preferable.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `na.locf` as suggested by Ananda Mahto is a good solution.  If you want to stay with base R, you can do this:

```
> udf<-unique(df)
> udf<-udf[udf$name != "",]
> df$name<-udf$name[match(df$id,udf$id)]
> df
  id name
1  1  sam
2  1  sam
3  1  sam
4  2 mike
5  2 mike
6  3  tom
```

On edit:  if you have a lot of data, `match` is going to be inefficient.  In this case, if you can guarantee that the `id` column in `df` is sorted, then `findInterval` is a better alternative:

```
df$name<-udf$name[findInterval(df$id,udf$id)]
```

In fact, even if `id` is not sorted, I would recommend first sorting it and then using `findInterval`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `na.locf` from the "zoo" package:

```
library(zoo)
df$name[df$name == ""] <- NA
na.locf(df)
#   id name
# 1  1  sam
# 2  1  sam
# 3  1  sam
# 4  2 mike
# 5  2 mike
# 6  3  tom
```

---

Sticking in base R, you can also try `aggregate` and `merge`:

```
merge(df, aggregate(as.character(name) ~ id, df, function(x) unique(x[x != ""])))
#   id name as.character(name)
# 1  1  sam                sam
# 2  1  sam                sam
# 3  1                     sam
# 4  2 mike               mike
# 5  2                    mike
# 6  3  tom                tom
```

The next step would be to drop the original "name" column and rename the newly created column.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use the ave function

```
df$name = ave(df$name, df$id,FUN = function(x) unique(x[x!=""]))
```